# Confirm ms account after installaion

Tags: 8.1, microsoft-account

2 days ago i reinstalled my lumia 920 running Windows Phone 8.1
After i logged in with my Microsoft account it asked for verification. (while it's a little stupid, because i use the authenticator which was installed)
I pressed 'not now' and it continues, but how can i verificate after the installation?

Answer (score -1):

You can use alternate methods (Call/Text) instead of using authenticator. There's an option for that in the registry wizard (before the not now option).

Comment: I know that, but i've skipped that verification

Comment: Goto Settings -> email & accounts -> Microsoft Account. Did you check this method?

Comment: Yes, i dont get a message to confirm my account or something

Comment: If You go to account.live.com in IE on your phone will you have to verify yourself then?